# How do I change an attribute of an element when someone scroll pass the element (Sticky Element)

Tags: javascript, jquery

For example http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/base-css.html try to scroll up. You will see the bar with

> "Typography Code Tables Forms Buttons Icons by Glyphicons"

when you scroll pass the element it will add a class to make the element change. While you are scrolling back up it will remove the attribute to change the element again.

Edit: I found out this is call Sticky Element.

Comment: What makes you think, its not on the page?

Comment: Your title are actual question is entirely different

Comment: It's on top of the page.

Comment: @Starx I will change it, it's a bit misleading.

Comment: @Jonathan, have you tried that plugin: http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/ ? That plugin you may specify action to perform once an element is outside of the "viewport".

Comment: @Cybrix I heard of it somewhere but it didn't seem useful to me at that time. Thanks, this will work for me.

Comment: Want me to put it as an answer? :D

Comment: @Cybrix sure, its a very good solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

THat jQUery plugin can do what you want: http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/

And here is an exemple taken from the URL:

```
someElements.waypoint(function(event, direction) {
   if (direction === 'down') {
      // do this on the way down
   }
   else {
      // do this on the way back up through the waypoint
   }
});
```

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

They are using addClass() function for this

```
$(".subnav").addClass("subnav-fixed");
```

Here is the function they are using for this

```
function processScroll() {
    var i, scrollTop = $win.scrollTop() //get the scroll position of the window object
    if (scrollTop >= navTop && !isFixed) { //check if its position is higher that the position of the navigation
    isFixed = 1 //if yes fix it
    $nav.addClass('subnav-fixed')
} else if (scrollTop <= navTop && isFixed) { //if is not higher then
    isFixed = 0
    $nav.removeClass('subnav-fixed') //un fix it
}
}
```

And they call this function on the scroll event of the document. May be something like

```
$(document).scroll(function() {
    processScroll();
});
```

Comment: I already know this, how did they detect if the element loses display on the page.

Comment: @JonathanShepherd, I have added some explanation as well.

Comment: I wish I could accept both answer :( but @Cybrix solution is more usable for me, sorry(I voted up all comments and answer for you)

Answer (score 0):

They are tracking the scroll position and modifying the class on the li elements

The sub-navigation bar you are seeing is implemented using ul and li elements. You can see from firebug:

```
<div class="subnav subnav-fixed">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills">
      <li class=""><a href="#typography">Typography</a></li>
      <li class=""><a href="#code">Code</a></li>
      <li class="active"><a href="#tables">Tables</a></li>
      <li class=""><a href="#forms">Forms</a></li>
      <li class=""><a href="#buttons">Buttons</a></li>
      <li class=""><a href="#icons">Icons by Glyphicons</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Notice how they are setting class='active' for the navigation element they want to make active.

With Jquery, you need to select that li element and change it class.
There are many ways to select the element you want (by id, child selector, class selector etc)
See http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

to change the class, you can use toggleClass, addClass and removeClass functions to manipulate the class of the element you want

For example, you could do

```
 //remove any active elements
 $("ul.nav > li").removeClass("active");
 //Make the 'Tables' subnav element active
 $("ul.nav > li:contains('Tables')").addClass("active");
```

Note that `:contains` might be a little heavy since it looks for all text inside the selected element. You can use other selectors such as :eq or nth-child
See http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/

```
$("ul.nav li:eq(2)").addClass( "active");
```

Comment: k i realized after answering that you already got other answers - nevermind